# Entropy-implied volatility requires itself to be calculated?

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, mathematics, estimation, normal-distribution

\begin{align}
H &= \frac{1}{2} \ln (2\pi\sigma^2) + \frac{1}{2}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \ln (2\pi e \sigma^2)
\end{align}
is the analytical solution for the **entropy** of a Gaussian random variable, such as a returns series, in the textbook *Financial Machine Learning*.

The author then re-works one of the above into a formula for **entropy-implied volatility** by isolating $\sigma$ by itself, and renaming it $\sigma_H$:

$$\sigma_{H} = \frac{e^{H} - \frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$

but isn't this useless because, in order to calculate $H$, you need sample volatility $\sigma$ anyway? In other words, to calculate $\sigma_H$, you need $H$, which itself in turn requires $\sigma$, meaning $\sigma = \sigma_H$. It's fair enough that $H$ is a function of $\sigma$, but $\sigma_H$ is a function of $H$ as well as its own self, $\sigma$

Is the $\sigma_H$ formula just a small exercise in algebra that is circularly redundant given that it itself ($\sigma$) is required as an input?

Comment: I think you estimate entropy from the data ($H$) and plug it into the estimator.

Comment: of course, but $H$ itself requires $\sigma$ as an input. That's the whole point of the question

Comment: I think that $H$ is assessed via an empirical entropy estimator from raw data, no?

Comment: but $H$ is the analytical solution for the Gaussian (not empirical) case, which in turn means $\sigma_H$ only admits the Gaussian (not empirical) $H$.

Comment: I think you would use some empirical estimator for $\hat{H}\equiv -\int f(x)log(f(x))dx$ and plug it in, no? Everything else would make no sense.

Comment: that's all I could think of, but as shown, $\sigma_H$ was derived from discrete entropy, not differential entropy. Not only discrete entropy, but discrete *Gaussian* entropy. Using differential entropy (which has no distributional assumptions) as an input to $\sigma_H$ (which is derived for Gaussian variables only) seems like it would refract the solution to a contrived, albeit incorrect, Gaussian one. Then again, I think alot of disregard is paid to the distributional rules of estimators all the time in finance